# Json Con Python

Tags: python, json

Tengo el siguiente resultado de una consulta :

```
res_query=((2, 'Lucero Matias', datetime.date(1988, 5, 6), '33524933', 'Malvinas Argentinas 597', 2687, 'Río Cuarto', 1, 'Argentina', 1, 'Base', 1, 'Particular', 1), (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988', 'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 2, 'Premium', 2, 'Aca Salud', 2), (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988', 'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 3, 'Soltero', 99, 'Agua Y Energia Cap. Federal', 4))
```

Quiero convertirlo a un Json del siguiente formato

```
[
    {
        "IdPaciente": 2,
        "Nombre": "Lucero Matias",
        "FNac": "1988-05-06",
        "Dni": "33524933",
        "Domicilio": "Malvinas Argentinas 597",
        "IdLoc": 2687,
        "NomLoc": "Rio Cuarto",
        "IdPais": 1,
        "NomPais": "Argentina",
        "OBRASOCIAL": [
            {
                "IdPlan": 1
                      "Plan": "Base",
                "IdOSoc": 1,
                "NomOSoc": "Particular",
                "IdPacPlan": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "IdPaciente": 6,
        "Nombre": "Sargiotto Alfonso",
        "FNac": "1993-01-07",
        "Dni": "38158988",
        "Domicilio": "Baigorria 55",
        "IdLoc": 128,
        "NomLoc": "Alejandro Roca",
        "IdPais": 1,
        "NomPais": "Argentina",
        "OBRASOCIAL": [
            {
                "IdPlan": 2,
                "Plan": "Premium",
                "IdOSoc": 2,
                "NomOSoc": "Aca Salud",
                "IdPacPlan": 2
            },
            {
                "IdPlan": 3,
                "Plan": "Soltero",
                "IdOSoc": 99,
                "NomOSoc": "Agua Y energia",
                "IdPacPlan": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Básicamente el problema lo tengo al crear el elemento "OBRA SOCIAL" que directamente no se como hacerlo.
Hay que tener en cuenta que un mismo IdPac puede tener dos o mas Obras Sociales, o solo tener una.
Por lo que debo recorrer el resultado de mi consulta analizar todas las columnas, aunque las que corresponen a datos personales son identicas para cada uno de los IdPac, por lo que no tengo inconveniente en que los datos "IdPaciente","Nombre","Fnac","Dni","Domicilio","IdLoc","NomLoc","IdPais"       "NomPais", se pisen. Donde varia es en OBRASOCIAL ya que contienen 1 o varios valores, cada key.
Espero que se entienda lo que estoy preguntando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más simple es usar un diccionario con la id  de cada paciente como clave y los datos de ese paciente (diccionario) como valor. Por cada fila miras si el diccionario tiene ya la clave, si la tiene simplemente agregas la nueva obra social a los datos ya existentes, si no existe se agregan todos los datos del paciente:

```
import datetime
import json

res_query=((2, 'Lucero Matias', datetime.date(1988, 5, 6), '33524933',
            'Malvinas Argentinas 597', 2687, 'Río Cuarto', 1,
            'Argentina', 1, 'Base', 1, 'Particular', 1),
           (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988',
            'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 2,
            'Premium', 2, 'Aca Salud', 2),
           (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988',
            'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 3,
            'Soltero', 99, 'Agua Y Energia Cap. Federal', 4)
           )

json_dat = {}
for row in res_query:
    id_paciente = row[0]

    obra_social = {
        "IdPlan": row[9],
        "Plan": row[10],
        "IdOSoc": row[11],
        "NomOSoc": row[12],
        "IdPacPlan": row[13]
        }

    if (pac:= json_dat.get(id_paciente)) is not None:
        pac["OBRASOCIAL"].append(obra_social)
    else:
        json_dat[id_paciente] = {
            "IdPaciente": id_paciente,
            "Nombre": row[1],
            "FNac": row[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "Dni": row[3],
            "Domicilio": row[4],
            "IdLoc": row[5],
            "NomLoc": row[6],
            "IdPais": row[7],
            "NomPais": row[8],
            "OBRASOCIAL": [obra_social]
            }


with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(list(json_dat.values()), fp, indent=4)
```

Lo que resulta en el siguiente JSON:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "IdPaciente": 2,
>         "Nombre": "Lucero Matias",
>         "FNac": "1988-05-06",
>         "Dni": "33524933",
>         "Domicilio": "Malvinas Argentinas 597",
>         "IdLoc": 2687,
>         "NomLoc": "R\u00edo Cuarto",
>         "IdPais": 1,
>         "NomPais": "Argentina",
>         "OBRASOCIAL": [
>             {
>                 "IdPlan": 1,
>                 "Plan": "Base",
>                 "IdOSoc": 1,
>                 "NomOSoc": "Particular",
>                 "IdPacPlan": 1
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "IdPaciente": 5,
>         "Nombre": "Sargiotto Alfonso",
>         "FNac": "1993-01-07",
>         "Dni": "38158988",
>         "Domicilio": "Baigorria 55",
>         "IdLoc": 128,
>         "NomLoc": "Alejandro Roca",
>         "IdPais": 1,
>         "NomPais": "Argentina",
>         "OBRASOCIAL": [
>             {
>                 "IdPlan": 2,
>                 "Plan": "Premium",
>                 "IdOSoc": 2,
>                 "NomOSoc": "Aca Salud",
>                 "IdPacPlan": 2
>             },
>             {
>                 "IdPlan": 3,
>                 "Plan": "Soltero",
>                 "IdOSoc": 99,
>                 "NomOSoc": "Agua Y Energia Cap. Federal",
>                 "IdPacPlan": 4
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> ]
> ```

Para Python < 3.8 (sin operador de asignación) se debe hacer:

```
import datetime
import json

res_query=((2, 'Lucero Matias', datetime.date(1988, 5, 6), '33524933',
            'Malvinas Argentinas 597', 2687, 'Río Cuarto', 1,
            'Argentina', 1, 'Base', 1, 'Particular', 1),
           (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988',
            'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 2,
            'Premium', 2, 'Aca Salud', 2),
           (5, 'Sargiotto Alfonso', datetime.date(1993, 1, 7), '38158988',
            'Baigorria 55', 128, 'Alejandro Roca', 1, 'Argentina', 3,
            'Soltero', 99, 'Agua Y Energia Cap. Federal', 4)
           )

json_dat = {}
for row in res_query:
    id_paciente = row[0]

    obra_social = {
        "IdPlan": row[9],
        "Plan": row[10],
        "IdOSoc": row[11],
        "NomOSoc": row[12],
        "IdPacPlan": row[13]
        }

    pac = json_dat.get(id_paciente)
    if pac is not None:
        pac["OBRASOCIAL"].append(obra_social)
    else:
        json_dat[id_paciente] = {
            "IdPaciente": id_paciente,
            "Nombre": row[1],
            "FNac": row[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "Dni": row[3],
            "Domicilio": row[4],
            "IdLoc": row[5],
            "NomLoc": row[6],
            "IdPais": row[7],
            "NomPais": row[8],
            "OBRASOCIAL": [obra_social]
            }


with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(list(json_dat.values()), fp, indent=4)
```

Comment: Es de alguna version de python en particular, porq me tira un erro en el if,
en esta linea
`código`if (pac:= json_dat.get(id_paciente)) is not None:`código`

Comment: Ahora actualizo, si es para Python >= 3.8...

Comment: Solo me genera el 2° paciente, y una sola OSoc
`[
    {
        "IdPaciente": 5,
        "Nombre": "Sargiotto Alfonso",
        "FNac": "1993-01-07",
        "Dni": "38158988",
        "Domicilio": "Baigorria 55",
        "IdLoc": 128,
        "NomLoc": "Alejandro Roca",
        "IdPais": 1,
        "NomPais": "Argentina",
        "OBRASOCIAL": [
            {
                "IdPlan": 3,
                "Plan": "Soltero",
                "IdOSoc": 3,
                "NomOSoc": "Agua Y Energia Cap. Federal",
                "IdPacPlan": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]`

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas mi ejemplo completo, tal como está?

Comment: Si si, identico a lo me pasaste

Comment: ???? Acabo de probar ambos códigos  (tal como están con ese contenido de `res_query`) de nuevo y la salida es la que muestro....

Comment: Dale, voy a seguir intentando a ver donde tengo el error, pero muchisimas gracias, si encuentro la solucion te la comparto, asi sabemos donde tengo el error

Comment: Ahi lo solucione, tenia un problema de indentación, tenia el for y el if y el else, en el mismo nivel, muchisimas gracias!